# how to include node_modules also while 'npm pack'

Tags: npm

I need to include some modules along with the application while 'npm pack'..
Do we have any option to include npm modules along with application?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside package.json, we can specify list of dependencies that need to be bundled while packaging.

```
....
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "dependency_1",
    "dependency_2"
]
....
```

More details on [bundledDependency can be found here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bundleddependencies)
It may be more manual work to maintain this list. To help this, there is a library called [bundle-deps](https://github.com/carlos8f/bundle-deps)

Usage

```
$ bundle-deps [path/to/project]
bundled 48 dependencies.
$ npm pack
// you will see the packaged file contains all your dependencies specified.
```

Alternatively, "bundledDependencies" can be defined as a boolean value. A value of true will bundle all dependencies, a value of false will bundle none.

[bundledDependencies documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bundleddependencies)

Comment: As per documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json: 

__Alternatively, "bundledDependencies" can be defined as a boolean value. A value of true will bundle all dependencies, a value of false will bundle none.__

We can now just write 


  "bundleDependencies": true,

And the dependencies get all bundled

Comment: Note that `bundleDependencies` is the default field name with [npm 8](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#bundledependencies), but `bundledDependencies` still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to depend on the `package` from your own `module` using something like Node.js' require, then you want to install locally, which is npm install's default behavior. On the other hand, if you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the `grunt CLI`, then you want to install it `globally`.
For further instructions please refer [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally)